# TaskbarIcon Class Creating Icon Everytime The Class Is Called WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, taskbar

I have a WPF application where I use the [TaskbarIcon class](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification/). This issue I have is, I call

```
static TaskbarIcon TBIcon = new TaskbarIcon();
```

in two separate classes hence creating two instances of it. One class uses it to create an icon, the other uses an inbuilt method to show Balloon Tips as apart of the classes methods.

The issue I have is whenever I create a new instance of the class it creates an icon (which is just a blank space) in my taskbar, so when I just use the class to show balloon tips I don't want it to automatically generate a blank space in my taskbar.

Is there any way to disable it from creating a blank icon? I tried to look for a method, although could only find `TBIcon.IsTaskbarIconCreated = false` however it is a read-only method.

**EDIT**: I've tried `TBIcon.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed` as well as `Visibility.Hidden` but both didn't work.

**EDIT SOLVED:**

I originally had a class as so:

```
class App 
{
    TaskbarIcon TBIcon = new TaskbarIcon();
    private void ShowStandardBalloon(string title, string text)
    {
        TBIcon.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        TBIcon.ShowBalloonTip(title, text, BalloonIcon.Info);
        TBIcon.HideBalloonTip();
    }
}
```

However I resolved the issue by create the class instance within the method as such:

```
class App 
{
    TaskbarIcon TBIcon;
    private void ShowStandardBalloon(string title, string text)
    {
        TBIcon = new TaskbarIcon()
        TBIcon.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        TBIcon.ShowBalloonTip(title, text, BalloonIcon.Info);
        TBIcon.HideBalloonTip();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use an if statement with this line `TBIcon.IsTaskbarIconCreated = false` , If it returns false then you create a new icon.

Comment: I posted my solution, but thankyou for your help @preciousbetine